# Где найти подобный плагин?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, плагин

Где можно найти подобный плагин или как он называется,
как на этом [сайте](http://promo.value1estates.com/) (при нажатии на картинку она увеличивается на весь экран и при отведении мышки она прокручивается в соответствующую сторону).

[image]

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере используется

https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel
+
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

возьмите на сайте где этот пример и посмотрите как там это реализовано

как вариант

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/sync.html

подогнать под свои нужды + add lightbox

Answer (score 0):

[Вот простой и понятный пример](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/02/modalnoe-okno-css.html) при помощи модального окна